# Solr: what are the default values for fields which does not have a default value explicitly set?

Tags: lucene, solr

I'm working with Solr's schema.xml, and I know that I can use the 'default' attribute to specify a default value which is to be used if a value for a given field has not been provided. However, say that I choose not to set the 'default' attribute, which default value will Solr then fall back to?

I would think that the field type which I've used for the given field would have a default value which would be used, but I have had not success finding any details about this. Alternatively, I'd think that not providing a value and not setting a default value effectively would be as if that field does not exist for the particular document.

However, I'm not sure and I'd like to know :-)

**UPDATE 1**

As far as I can see, Solr just throws an error and returns an error 400 "Bad Request" if no default value has been set and no value has been provided for a given field. In other words, Solr does not seem to apply any "fallback" default values in case no value is provided and no default value has been set in schema.xml.

**UPDATE 2**

My above update seems to be wrong. If no value has been provided for a field and no default value has been set for that field, then Solr will just treat the field as if it does not exist for that particular document. This behaviour does, of course, not apply if the field is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience if you do not specify a field when loading documents, then Solr will just ignore that field when it indexes the document and your statement "not providing a value and not setting a default value effectively would be as if that field does not exist for the particular document" is true. The catch is that you need to only specify the fields that you want to add for the given document. Check out the xml exampledocs that come with the Solr Distribution to see some examples of files that contain differing field sets.

Comment: That's weird. I tried to index a document by intentionally leaving out one of the fields set up in schema.xml. Solr then gave me a 400 "Bad Request". Once I provided a value for that field during indexing Solr was once again happy. Do you remember wether  you have explicitly set the 'default' attribute for each field in schema.xml?

Comment: No I do not have the `default` attribute set for any of my fields. The only field I would expect to get an issue from if I did not specify a value, would be the field that is identified in the `uniqueKey` setting.

Comment: It seems that you are right, and that my "Bad Request" somehow must have been caused by something else. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't supply value for field during indexing, solr will use default value as defined in schema.xml file. If default is not defined, solr ignores this field. If field is marked as required in schema.xml - solr will reject this document with error.

Example:

```
<field name="comments" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Though you define fields in file called `schema.xml`, Solr documents are in fact **schemeless**. That means that internally Solr engine (Lucene) doesn't have any definitions of fields each document must have. With Lucene you can easily add field `myCompletelyNewField` to any document without affecting other documents anyhow.

So, what is the reason for `schema.xml`? Each field in Solr/Lucene has several properties, most known of them are `indexed` and `stored` properties. Moreover, all fields must be bound to some internal data type and processing units. For example, `id` field must be stored as string, and `description` field must be analyzed with some English analyzer, cleaned with stopwords filter and so on. Passing all this information in the `add` request to Solr is very inconvenient. Since you know what fields you will use and have access to Solr server (in most cases, at least), it is much easier to move all this info to separate file. And this file is `schema.xml`.

So, now you must understand that `schema.xml` define fields that are **allowed**, but not fields that *must exist* in document. Additional modifiers like `required` and `default` just provide additional services before adding documents to the index. I.e. `required` will force Solr's "front-end" to check whether specified field exists in new document. If yes, it passes document further, otherwise it rejects new doc. `default` causes same check, but if field is absent, it adds it with default values and passes document further.

As for your "Bad Request" error, I guess you have error somewhere else, e.g. you add empty field (field exist, but its value is "") while it is not allowed, or use incorrect value for the field, or have some other modifiers that contradict actual field added.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It all makes sense, and i appreciate your thorough description of how it works behind the scenes!